# How to setup Gatling to use client certificates per virtual user?

Tags: ssl, gatling, scala-gatling

How to setup Gatling to use client certificates per virtual user?

I am preparing Gatling simulations for API that is protected by client certificates and currently I only managed to set using one client certificate for all simulations in Gatling configuration

```
ssl {
  keyStore {
    #type = ""
    file = "C:/client_certificates/00001.pfx"
    password = "password"
    #algorithm = ""
  }
}
```

However, I would like to have different client certificates for different virtual users (client certificates can be selected randomly from the list of available client certificates or circularly). Galing documentation mentions [keymanagerfactory](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/#keymanagerfactory) and `perUserKeyManagerFactory` function, but without explicit examples of how to use it.

Comment: Try `perUserKeyManagerFactory(userId => io.gatling.commons.util.Ssl.newTrustManagerFactory(None, f"C:/client_certificates/$userId%05d.pfx", "password", None))`

Comment: @George Leung, `newKeyManagerFactory` should be used instead of `newTrustManagerFactory`. Otherwise your solution works! Could you please post an answer? I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keys of the config provided in the question are referenced in `io.gatling.core.ConfigKeys.ssl.keyStore`. The values are read and passed to `Ssl.newKeyManagerFactory` to create a `KeyManagerFactory`.

---

`perUserKeyManagerFactory` takes in a function `Long => KeyManagerFactory` that constructs the `KeyManagerFactory` from the virtual user's ID.

---

Knowing that we can write the following:

```scala
import io.gatling.commons.util.Ssl

...
.perUserKeyManagerFactory { userId =>
  val fileName = f"C:/client_certificates/$userId%05d.pfx"
  Ssl.newKeyManagerFactory(None, fileName, "password", None)
}
```

With [the `f` interpolator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-f-interpolator), we can easily pad the `userId` with zeros to have 5 digits.

To select the files circularly, we can write `${userId % totalNumber}` instead of `$userId`.