# One client certificate per user in Gatling scenario?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to define a Gatling scenario using a different client certificate per user.
I am using Gatling 3.7.1. The hints (e.g. this one [How to setup Gatling to use client certificates per virtual user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086692/how-to-setup-gatling-to-use-client-certificates-per-virtual-user)) I found do not work anymore with the new Gatling versions. The Ssl class does not exist anymore since Gatling 3.4

Gatling documentation states to use:

```
http.perUserKeyManagerFactory(userId => null.asInstanceOf[javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory])
```

However, I have no glue how I can inject the user dependent key store?
I tried to set the properties gatling.ssl.keyStore.file and the related password property in the session context but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

That's plain Java, for example like in [here](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory).